# How to get a IBM MQ message by Message ID using bash ? is there a tool available?

Tags: ibm-mq

Looking to get an IBM MQ message by Message ID using bash

Is there a tool readily available ? can any of the bash samples that come MQ installation serve the purpose? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could issue a CURL command to invoke the REST API in your bash script.

eg.

```
curl -X DELETE --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://HOST:PORT/ibmmq/rest/v3/messaging/qmgr/QM1/queue/DEV.QUEUE.1/message?messageId=MSGID'
```

Substitute

- MSGID for your message ID
- HOST for your queue manager address
- PORT for your queue manager REST port
- QM1 for the queue manager
- DEV.QUEUE.1 for the queue

Answer (score 0):

There is no MQ API for Bash.  You can use  C, C++, C#, COBOL, PL/I, Java, Rexx, RPG, Perl and Python. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_MQ#APIs

If you want to use a scripting language with MQ then I'd suggest using either Python or REXX.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is the [q.exe](https://mqgem.com/q.html) formerly known as Support Pac MA01 that is now licensed by MQGem.